# Load whole page before javascript runs

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to set the length of an accepted input in the input box by using radio buttons. However every time I try to do this I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null'. After searching I have realised this is because JavaScript elements are loading before the whole HTML code can run. Though I cannot not find any code that is able to load the whole page then run the JavaScript that works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'en'>
<meta charset = 'UTF-8'/>
<head>
    <h2> Credit Card </h2>  
    <script src= 'card.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'card' value = 'visa'> Visa </input>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'card' value = 'mastercard'> Mastercard </input>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'card' value = 'americanexpress'> American Express </input> <br />
    <input type = 'number' id = 'cardnumber'/> <br />
    <button type = 'button' id = 'confirm' onclick = 'proceed()'> Click to proceed </button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried `windows.onload` but it hasn't worked for me. It is highly likely I wasn't using it right.

```
var cardLength = 0;
if (document.getElementById('visa').checked || document.getElementById('mastercard').checked) {
    cardLength = 16;
} else if (document.getElementById('americanexpress').checked) {
    cardLength = 15;
}

function proceed() {
    var check = document.getElementById('proceed').value;
    if (check == cardLength) {
        alert('Proceed')
    } else {
        alert('Card length invalid')
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get element by id 'visa', 'mastercard' and 'americanexpress', but there isn't elements with this id's.

Add id's to your input fields like in the code below.

Also try to include js files at the end of `<body>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'en'>
<meta charset = 'UTF-8'/>
<head>
    <h2> Credit Card </h2>
</head>
<body>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'card' value = 'visa' id='visa'> Visa </input>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'card' value = 'mastercard' id='mastercard'> Mastercard     </input>
    <input type = 'radio' name = 'card' value = 'americanexpress' id='americanexpress'> American Express </input> <br />
    <input type = 'number' id = 'cardnumber'/> <br />
    <script src= 'card.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then what is the point of value? Also, this does not solve the inherent problem

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues affecting this.

1) You are correct in that the JS is being loaded before the rest of the HTML. You mentioned that you attempted to use `window.onload`? Can you please specify how? The following code works:

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert(document.querySelector('[name="card"]:checked').value)
}
```

Otherwise, I would highly recommend placing your script tag at the bottom of the html, just before the closing `</body>` tag instead. This has a couple benefits: It loads as you had intended, and it doesn't block the HTML, so to the user, depending on the size of you final script, it loads slightly faster.

2) As lanokvova said, you have no elements with the id of 'visa', 'mastercard', or 'americanexpress'. You can add the ids, or you can use `document.querySelector('[name="card"]:checked')`, as seen above.

3) You're only running this once on startup. If the user selects a different card, it's not going to update. I would recommend using jQuery for this, as it's significantly cleaner, but it can be done in vanilla JS like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name="card"]').forEach(function(a) {
    a.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var selected = this.value;

        if(selected === 'visa' || selected === 'mastercard') {
            cardLength = 16;
        } else if(selected === 'americanexpress') {
            cardLength = 15;
        }
    });
});
```

A working demo can be found on [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q68u7gc/2/). You'll just need to update your script to the JS block, and move the tag to the end of the HTML.

Btw, you don't need to close `<input>` tags, and that `<h2>` should go inside the body, not the head.

Comment: Actually, since you're only using this for validation on submit, I would just [condense it all into the proceed function](https://jsfiddle.net/t6t3hLwf/). In this case, you can just leave it in the head if you really wanted to (but I'd still recommend moving it to the end of the body).